# React not triggering re-render with useState hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, react-hooks

I have a form component structured by categories > fields > then multiple validity rows per field. I keep track of the form value state (the validity rows per field ID) with useState(). There is an add button in a child component that triggers `addValidityRowCallback` to add another validity row.

I am trying to update the state and trigger a re-render but it doesn't seem to work.

```
import React, {useState} from 'react'
import CollapsibleFieldset from "../../fieldsets/CollapsibleFieldset";
import PersonInfoTypeFormRow from "./PersonInfoTypeFormRow";
import cloneAndUpdate from 'immutability-helper';


export default function PersonInfoForm({personInfoFormDataJson, webServiceAddress}) {

    let [targetPersonId, formCategories, defaultFormValuesIndexedById] = parsePersonInfoJsonString(personInfoFormDataJson);

    const [ formValuesById, setFormValues ] = useState(defaultFormValuesIndexedById);

    const addValidityRowCallback = (personInfoTypeId) => {
        let newEmptyRow = {id:12345, value:["NEW"], valueTitle:"","validityStartDate":"",createdDateTime:"",createdByPersonId:1212};
        let newFormValuesState = cloneAndUpdate(formValuesById, {});
        newFormValuesState[personInfoTypeId].push(newEmptyRow);
        setFormValues(newFormValuesState);
    };

    return <form className="personInfoForm pure-form">
            {formCategories.map((category) => {
                return <CollapsibleFieldset key={category.id || category.title} legend={category.title}>
                    {category.personInfoTypes.map((personInfoType) => {
                        return <PersonInfoTypeFormRow {...personInfoType} key={personInfoType.id} addValidityRowCallback={addValidityRowCallback} values={formValuesById[personInfoType.id]}/>
                    })}
                </CollapsibleFieldset>
            })
            {/* DEBUG........ */}
            {Object.keys(formValuesById).map(fieldId => {
                return formValuesById[parseInt(fieldId)].map(validityRow => {
                    return <h3 key={validityRow.id}>{validityRow.id}</h3>
                })
            })}
        }
    </form>;
}
```

I can see in the debugger that my `addValidityRowCallback` function is called correctly, clones the existing state, adds a new row at the correct point in the structure, then passes the new state back to `setFormValues()` but no re-render?

**UPDATE**: I've fixed this (although admittedly don't fully understand why my original didn't work), see my answer below

Comment: What does your cloneAndUpdate() method look like?

Comment: can you post a codesandbox for your problem!

Comment: @christopher-ngo cloneAndUpdate() is the update method from immutability-helper library https://github.com/kolodny/immutability-helper

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I fixed this by updating the object through the `cloneAndUpdate` ([Hooks API Reference](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html)) method instead of afterwards

```
assign[personInfoTypeId] = {$push:[newEmptyRow]};
let newPersonInfoTypeFieldsState = cloneAndUpdate(formValuesById,assign);
setFormValues(newFormValuesState);
```

I think the library isn't actually doing a deep copy but re-using parts of the structure that haven't changed so I suspect trying to manually update this afterwards was actually updating the original reference that react new about and thus react recognised no difference when setting state. Using the correct `$push` syntax documented in the library fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you render `formCategories` but set `formValuesById` to the state. So instead if saving `formValuesById` on the state, you need to save `formCategories`.

Comment: I thought that might be the case so I output some info from `formValuesById` directly and it doesn't seem to help (I've updated my OP with the debug I used) and it still doesn't trigger a re-render. I'm now wondering if my "cloned" object is triggering the diff

Comment: It seems like you have quite complex state. Why don't you try `useReducer` instead of `useState`? https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer